# How to map a tree in a stack safe manner?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, iterator, tail-recursion

There are different ways to map a tree recursively:

```js
const reduceTree = (f, node) => {
  const go = ([x, xs]) => f(x, xs.map(go));
  return go(node);
};

const mapTree = (f, node) =>
  reduceTree((x, xs) => Node_(f(x), xs), node);

const Node_ = (x, xs) => ([x, xs]);
const Node = (x, ...xs) => ([x, xs]);

const tree = Node(1,
  Node(2,
    Node(3),
    Node(4,
      Node(5))),
  Node(6),
  Node(7,
    Node(8),
    Node(9),
    Node(10),
    Node(11)));

console.log(
  mapTree(x => 2 * x, tree));
```

This is in fact an elegant solution, however, it is not stack safe. Since the recursive call (`xs.map(go)`) isn't in tail position, I can't fall back to a trampoline and it doesn't seem trivial to me to transform the algorithm in tail recursive form.

The usual way to do this is probably a CPS transformation, which kind of obfuscates the computation. Maybe there is another way to achieve stack safety - with a generator, for instance? Are there general rules for such a transformation, which can be applied in an almost mechanical way?

I am primarily interested in the process of doing this transformation not in the final result.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: Why do you care if it obfuscates the code, though? You write `reduceTree()` once, and the complexity is hidden inside it. That's the point of writing higher-order functions.

Comment: A common way to make a recursive function tail-recursive is by passing an extra argument to hold the accumulated result.

Comment: I am sympathetic to this question, but as far as I know it's still only Safari that implements tail-call optimization.

Comment: Whether loop or tail recursion, to traverse a tree without recursive branching you need a stack. The solution is [exactly the same as to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55933861/1048572).

Comment: @Pointy I just wanted to make the mapping ready for using it on a trampoline. Sure, tail recursion is structurally half way to loops but still avoids reassignments. In my opinion this trait is worth the extra layer of complexity the trampoline entails.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a well-formed mutually recursive pair -

```
// map :: (a -> b, Tree a) -> Tree b
const map = (f, [ v, children ]) =>
  Node (f (v), ...mapAll (f, children))

// mapAll :: (a -> b, [ Tree a ]) -> [ Tree b ]
const mapAll = (f, nodes = []) =>
  nodes .map (n => map (f, n))
```

We first remove the eager `Array.prototype.map` which cannot possibly allow a tail form -

```
const map = (f, [ v, children ]) =>
  Node (f (v), ...mapAll (f, children))

const mapAll = (f, [ node, ...more ]) =>
  node === undefined
    ? []
    : [ map (f, node), ...mapAll (f, more) ]
```

Next add the parameter for CPS conversion -

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const map = (f, [ v, children ], k = identity) =>
  mapAll (f, children, newChilds =>        // tail
    k (Node (f (v), ...newChilds)))        // tail

const mapAll = (f, [ node, ...more ], k = identity) =>
  node === undefined
    ? k ([])                               // tail
    : map (f, node, newNode =>             // tail
        mapAll (f, more, moreChilds =>     // tail
          k ([ newNode, ...moreChilds ]))) // tail
```

---

Verify the results in your own browser below

```js
const Node = (x, ...xs) =>
  [ x, xs ]

const identity = x =>
  x

const map = (f, [ v, children ], k = identity) =>
  mapAll (f, children, newChilds =>
    k (Node (f (v), ...newChilds)))
  
const mapAll  = (f, [ node, ...more ], k = identity) =>
  node === undefined
    ? k ([])
    : map (f, node, newNode =>
        mapAll (f, more, moreChilds =>
          k ([ newNode, ...moreChilds ])))

const tree = 
  Node
    ( 1
    , Node
        ( 2
        , Node (3)
        , Node
            ( 4
            , Node (5)
            )
        )
    , Node (6)
    , Node
        ( 7
        , Node (8)
        , Node (9)
        , Node (10)
        , Node (11)
        )
    )

console.log (map (x => x * 10, tree))
```

Note, CPS on its own doesn't make the program stack-safe. It's just the form required to put the code on a trampoline of your choice.

Comment: You should add that CPS does actually not make it stack safe, on the contrary your solution will have more problems with deep trees than the original.

Comment: @Bergi I think you telepathically entered my mind before your comment arrived. I put a note at the end :D

Comment: You've changed the original types `reduceTree :: (a,  [b] -> b), Tree a -> b` / `mapTree :: (a -> b), T a -> T b`. Is there a special reason for this?

Comment: I wanted the mapping to become trampoline material - should have been more explicit about this.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah, CPS sucks! However, it is the only way to render a recursive, stack depending function tail recursive. JS should be shipped with TCO since ES2015. But we were betrayed by the industry :D.

Comment: So ultimately this boils down to the question what is less convoluted: algorithms in CPS form or in iterative form (loops).